# Moving contents from one file to a new one in python

Tags: python, file, printing

i want to print in the even file all even numbers with spaces between them eg: `12 6 20 10` not `1262010` with no spaces in front or back. How can i do this?

```
def write_positive_even_to_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as orginal, open('xxx.txt', 'a') as even:
        red = orginal.read().split()
        for number in red:
            if number % 2 == 0:
                even.write(number + " ")
```

Input file:

```
15 12 6
7 20 9 10
13 17
3
```

Comment: Does the input file contain a single line with whitespace separated integers?

Comment: @Vlad No not a single line but many... i just edited my qs to include it

Answer (score 0):

You need to split each input line into tokens (assumed to represent integers) convert to int then determine if any value is even.

Something like this:

```
def write_positives(infile, outfile, mode='a'):
    with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, mode) as fout:
        if (evens := [x for x in map(int, fin.read().split()) if x % 2 == 0]):
            print(*evens, file=fout)
```

By printing the unpacked list you will, by default, have space separation

Comment: @AhmadYeaseenKhan Thank you for pointing that out. Edited accordingly

Comment: @AhmadYeaseenKhan No it won't